# Shklyarov's Euler class in geometrical setting

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, differential-graded-algebras

In paper [HIRZEBRUCH-RIEMANN-ROCH THEOREM FOR DG ALGEBRAS](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0710.1937.pdf) Shklyarov provides construction which for a given dg-algebra (over field $k$, proper, $k$-smooth) $A$ and perfect $A$-module $M$ associate en element $\operatorname{eu}(M)$ in $HH_0(A)$, but the construction is not very straightforward: we should represent our perfect $A$-module as twisted dg $A$-module at first and after that, we have to make some hard computations. Could we simplify the construction in a purely geometric case? I mean, suppose we have some smooth proper $n$-dimensional algebraic variety $X$ over a field $k$ and coherent sheaf $\mathcal F$ on it, interpreted as an element of $\mathcal{Perf}-X$ (with some dg-enhancement), is there exists a more straightforward description of $\operatorname{eu}(\mathcal{F})$ as the element of 
$$HH_0(X) := \bigoplus_{p=0}^n H^p(X, \Omega_X^p)$$
? For example, can we compute $\operatorname{eu}(\mathcal{F})$ in the case when $X=\mathbb P^n, \mathcal F = \mathcal{O}(k)$?

Comment: Well it should certainly give a multiple of the chern character (valued in Hodge cohomology). As for how to prove this I imagine it won't be any simpler than carefully tracing through the steps honestly identifying HH of the category of perfect complexes on X. I think the point Shklyarov makes (and its a good point!) is that RRoch type index theorems are really computations of HH of a certain category, once u have that u expect a RRoch theorem abstractly, and then carefully tracing through the steps u can hope to identify the chern classes he constructs

Comment: Perhaps u'd like to see what it says for quiver reps, in which case u can do the case of the proj line in terms of the Kronecker quiver I suppose

Comment: Useful remarks, thank you!